# No server runtime environment for GlassFish on eclipse kepler?

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I am using Eclipse Kepler and GlassFish tools plungin. After I upgraded the latest version of GlassFish tools (6.5.0.201405081811) and other eclipse components, the Server Runtime Environment for GlassFish is gone.

The Server Runtime Environment only has Apache, Basic, JBoss and ObjectWeb. I can't start up GF server in eclipse anymore.

I am using JDK1.6 to startup eclipse, I don't know whether this is the root cause.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem.  Un-installing, then re-installing the glassfish tools did the trick for me.